# Where is the page spending its time

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, curl

I have on page which shows available hotel rooms and book button against them. Availability of a rooms list say 5 is checked using jquery async ajax. In PHP on server side the availability is handled by separate curl requests originating from the same file.

Now once a room's availability is returned we enable a link to be shown to the user which is an anchor tag with checkout page URL.

After receiving first availability if I try to click on a link then after the click the page spends around 20 seconds waiting for something I don't know. I can see in console that the other ajax requests which have not given results are already aborted. Now where is this page spending its time after click before moving on to the checkout page.

Once the first link gets clicked rest of the requests get automatically aborted. And now in the browser I can see the loading icon but nothing happens for the next 20 seconds. And after 20 seconds I get the checkout page.
Let me know in case more details are needed.

Thanks.

Posting code of javascript for ajax requests:

```
var xhrRequests = [];

function filterByCancellation(){
    $( ".hotel_package_row:visible" ).each(function( index ) {
        var cancellation_obj = $(this).find( ".cancellationText" );
        var pack_price = 0;
        var hotel_price = 0;
        if ($(cancellation_obj).text()=="") {
            var hotelid = $(cancellation_obj).prev("a").data( "hotelid"),
                packid  = $(cancellation_obj).prev("a").data( "packid"),
                cancel  = $(cancellation_obj);
            if(!$('#anc-'+packid).is(':visible') && $('#inp-'+packid).val()=="0"){
                $('#inp-'+packid).val("1");
                cancel.html('').slideToggle(function(){
                    var data = { hotelid: hotelid, packid: packid };
                    pack_price = parseInt($('#packprice_'+packid).val());
                    var xhr = $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "location_penny.php?section=cancellationData",
                      data: data,
                      success: function(result) {
                        //cancel.html(result);
                        if(result.indexOf('<div style="display:none;">') > -1){
                            $(cancellation_obj).parents('.hotel_package_row').html('');
                        }else{
                            hotel_price = parseInt($('#'+hotelid).find('.currency-sign-before').html());
                            if($("#price_update_"+hotelid).val()=='0'){
                                //alert("hotel price "+hotel_price+" updating for the first time with package "+pack_price);
                                $('#'+hotelid).find('.currency-sign-before').html(pack_price);
                                $("#price_update_"+hotelid).val("1");
                            }
                            if(pack_price<=hotel_price){
                                //alert("hotel price "+hotel_price+" is greater than current package price "+pack_price);
                                $('#'+hotelid).find('.currency-sign-before').html(pack_price);
                            }
                            $('#img-'+packid).hide();
                            $('#anc-'+packid).show();
                        }
                      },
                      async:true
                    });
                    xhrRequests.push(xhr);
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

function cancelXhrRequests(){
    for (var i = 0; i < xhrRequests.length; i++) {
        xhrRequests[i].abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your Network tab for long pending requests.

Comment: I checked it. Once the first link gets clicked rest of the requests get automatically aborted. And now in the browser I can see the loading icon but nothing happens for the next 20 seconds. And after 20 seconds I get the checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe caused by redirected URLs or something like that. Apache has two log file saved on `/var/log` folder (based on your Linux distributions):

- Debian base distr.: `/var/log/apache2/error_log` and `/var/log/apache2/access_log`
- RedHat base distr: `/var/log/httpd/error_log` and `/var/log/httpd/access_log`.

So you can use tail command on continues mode (i.e. `tail -f ADDRESS_OF_LOG_FILE`) for observing your requests and error occurred on processing them.

Comment: Right now I am checking it on my local and I am using XAMPP. The thing is that the link which it has to go is from http://127.0.0.1:8080/almo_live/index.php?show=search_hotel to http://127.0.0.1:8080/almo_live/index.php?show=checkoutpage. Now it takes 20 seconds when an anchor is clicked. I tried replacing the target link with https://google.com and it went without wasting a second. Like instantaneously. What could be the reason ?

Comment: Can you post some parts of your code on the main question?

Comment: Added code which calls ajax requests. If anything else is needed. Kindly let me know specific parts.

Comment: @Anoop : Your first comment is vital information to understanding your problem. Please move it you a logical place in your question. As people ask questions about your problem, improve your question, and use comments to tell reader that you have updated your question. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter  Done. Thanks.